# How to check my spring Ioc container

Tags: java, spring, logging

I'm new of spring and i want to check the situation of my Ioc container. Try to explain with more detail my problem, I have the following spring configuration, where i definited the component scan on same packege in this way:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.myCompany"/>
```

In these packages there are many spring bean with differente scope, and many time I encountered some problem with the autowired. Then summarizing, I would want to know if is there some tool or logging system that could show me the situation of my spring's IoC container. For example I want somethings like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ContextRefreshedEvent` event tells application that context has initialized. You can check example code below:

```
@Component 
public class MyAppListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationContextEvent> 
{

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextEvent arg0) {

    if (arg0 instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
      // Context is ready
    }
  }
}
```